# Erro ao selecionar parte de uma string no select de uma entidade usando Entity Framework e Linq

Tags: c#, linq

Eu preciso montar um Drop-down com parte do nome de um projeto, que é muito grande no banco de dados, vai até 250 caracteres.
Para isto fiz um seletor assim:

```
var lista = _projetoAppServ.ObterTodos("Descricao")
      .Select( a => new { 
                          ProjetoId= a.ProjetoId, 
                          Descricao = a.Descricao.Substring(0,50) 
                        })
```

Porém, há projetos com menos de 50 caracteres, ocasionando o erro abaixo:
O índice e o comprimento devem se referir a um local dentro da cadeia de caracteres.
Nome do parâmetro: length

Como solucionar este problema?

Comment: Acabei de encontrar uma solução: var lista = _projetoAppServ.ObterTodos("Descricao").Select( a => new { ProjetoId= a.ProjetoId, Descricao = ( (a.Descricao.Length > 50) ? a.Descricao.Substring(0,50) : a.Descricao ) });

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode utilizar o PadRight para preencher com espaços.

```
var lista = _projetoAppServ.ObterTodos("Descricao")
      .Select( a => new { 
                          ProjetoId= a.ProjetoId, 
                          Descricao = a.Descricao.PadRight(50, ' ').Substring(0,50) 
                        })
```